# Derivates with respect to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have an equation, $f = X^TY + \dots$ (a few more terms), where $X$ is a vector and $Y$ is a matrix of appropriate dimensions,
I want to know how can we take the derivative of $f \text{ w.r.t. } X$? I understand differentiation w.r.t one variable, but how does differentiation of another vector/matrix w.r.t a vector work?

Differentiating a function w.r.t a variable gives us the rate at with the function changes when we change the variable by a small amount. What does differentiating w.r.t a vector signify?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2165835/278230

Comment: If you want more, check this thread and PDF from Jeremy Howards and Terrence http://forums.fast.ai/t/preview-release-matrix-calculus-for-deep-learning/10526

Answer (score 1):

$f =X^T Y$ looks like this
\begin{equation}
 f= \begin{pmatrix}
  \sum_i x_iy_{i1}\\
  \sum_i x_iy_{i2}\\
  \vdots\\
  \sum_i x_iy_{in}\\
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ element of $X$ and $y_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)^{th}$ element of $Y$.
Now, to get the gradient w.r.t $X$, is equivalent to deriving each element of $f$ w.r.t each element of $X$. This will lead to a 2D matrix:
\begin{equation}
 \nabla_X f = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f_1 & \ldots & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} f_1\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f_n & \ldots & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} f_n
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
We can therefore easily see that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f_i
=
y_{ij}
\end{equation} 
Therefore $\nabla_X f = Y$.

Answer (score -1):

Derivative of a univariate vector is the same as sum of derivatives of its component(Addition rule for differentiation).

As for an extra $Y$ matrix in multiplication with $X^T$, the derivative of $f$ is calculated using partial derivative rule.

Please see the link [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/partial-derivative-and-gradient-articles/a/introduction-to-partial-derivatives).